# Unable to run multiple feature file through Karate UI

Tags: karate

I wish to run multiple feature files through karate UI through code only.
Karate UI gives feature to execute cucumber feature files one after another but I wish to open UI through code which is fine using `app.run(arg1, arg2)` but there I can not use three arguments.

If i put multiple `app.run(feature1, arg1), app.run(feature2, arg2)` in the code then it picks up only the first feature1 file.

Comment: I think this one is still pending. Tried it with the suggestion that you gave but no luck so far. Will work on that soon.

Comment: Deleted as of now. will bug you once I start working on that :)

Comment: just answered below. I really think you are un-necessary going in the wrong direction. just use the parallel runner or tags or `@CucumberOptions` pointing to a package. why are you trying to do this !!

Comment: As of now, I am using @CucumberOptions but I think the motive of using Karate UI should be the same.

Comment: you do know that the UI is experimental right ? read the docs. please contribute missing features for the ui, this is open source

Comment: Seems like I need access to the karate to send a pull request. Could you please help me in getting the same.

Comment: no you don't need access to Karate. please read up on how to submit pull requests to Git projects.

Comment: Cool on my way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the scope of the UI is for developers to work on one test at a time. It sounds like you are planning to use it as a test-runner and for multiple files.

Currently this is not supported but thanks for bringing it up, I've opened a feature request here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/370

That said are you sure you are not missing an easier way to do what you want which is to simply use the Karate runners that can run multiple features and that too with rich reporting ?

EDIT: This has been implemented in Karate 0.8.0